# Bind javascript swipe and onclick events to iframe which has pdf document in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe in html5 which has pdf document as its source. Want to perform something on click and swipe events of iframe element. I have tried binding events but events are not triggering for iframe. How do i capture these events for iframe ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not possible.*

The PDF is displayed inside the iframe by the PDF browser plugin just like flash content is displayed by the flash plugin. You cannot capture the events from inside the plugin container view like you can capture other DOM events.